# shm_open with mmap giving bus error only in one particular machine

Tags: c, linux

I have the following simple program to create a shared memory. But this is giving

> Bus error (core dumped)

This is happening only on one virtual machine and I tried the same code in mutiple VM and in every other machine this is working correctly. But only on one machine this issue is happening. Can anyone point me the issue. All my machines are running on **2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64** . Will this be a kernel issue or application issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char *shpath="/shm_path_for_data";
        void *memPtr;
        shm_unlink(shpath);
        int fd=0;
        fd = shm_open(shpath, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0777);
        if(fd<0) {
                printf("shm_open failed\n");
                return 1;
        }
        if((ftruncate(fd, getpagesize())) <0) {
                printf("Ftruncate failed\n");
                return 1;
        }

        memPtr = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if(memPtr == MAP_FAILED) {
                return 1;
        }
        strcpy((char *)memPtr, "test input.Just copying something\n");
        printf("mapped out: %s\n", (char *)memPtr);
}
```

Comment: curious, why the cast to `(char *)`?

Comment: What is the faulting line of code that caused the SIGSEGV? If you don't know, then please run your code under gdb to find out.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart We both missed it, see my answer.

Comment: Bus error is happening when I try to access the memory area. So here its happening on the memcpy itself. I tried with strcpy also. But bus error is happening on the same line when I try writing on the memory area

Comment: what happens if you set `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and pass in `-1` as fd, instead of shm?

Comment: I just used **MAP_ANONYMOUS**  and its working fine.  `memPtr = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You are copying 50 bytes

```
memcpy((char *)memPtr, "test input.Just copying something\n", 50);
/* BTW: ^ this cast is unneeded */
```

there are only 36 available, so you are reading beyond the string literal, which is undefined behavior, that's why it works on one machine and fails on another, that's how undefined behavior behaves.

Try

```
strcpy((char *) memPtr, "Test input. Just copying something\n");
```

Comment: Doh! Had nothing to do with mmap or shm. Good catch. (I probably saw the mmap/shm usage and assumed the OP knew better than to overrun this string literal).

Comment: I changed to strcpy and no luck this time too.. Giving same bus error.