# Getting a Bus Error when using memset() in C?

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap, memset, bus-error

I'm making a program that uses shared memory and mmap to communicate between different processes/threads, but I keep getting a Bus Error at runtime. I've isolated the error and it seems it happens right after memset() gets executed. Did I set up my memory map incorrectly?
 unsigned char *create_bitmap(unsigned long max)

```
 92 unsigned char *create_bitmap(unsigned long max)
 93 {
 94     int fd;
 95     unsigned long object_size = (max + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char);
 96     unsigned char *address;
 97
 98 //  fd = open("/dev/zero",O_RDWR);
 99     fd = shm_open("./morriluk_bitmap", O_RDWR|O_CREAT , S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR );
100     if(fd == -1){
101         perror("Unable to open morriluk_bitmap");
102         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
103     }
104     printf("1\n");
105     if(ftruncate(fd, object_size) == -1){
106         perror("Unable to resize morriluk_bitmap");
107         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
108     }
109     printf("2\n");
110
111     address = (unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, object_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
112     if (address == MAP_FAILED) {
113         perror("Unable to mmap morriluk_bitmap to any address");
114         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
115     }
116     printf("3\n");
117
118     memset((void *)address, PRIME, object_size);
119     printf("4\n");
120
121     return address;
122 }
```

Command line output:

```
creating bitmap
1
2
3
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Comment: When you call create_bitmap(), what is the value of "max"? There are a few similar questions on SO like this one that suggest one possible cause is a buffer that's not sized properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056508/shm-open-with-mmap-giving-bus-error-only-in-one-particular-machine

Comment: The value of max is the value UINT_MAX as set by limit.h.
I think the numerical value is something along the lines of 4,294,967,295. Also, it seems like this bus error only happens when "max" is large. I tried it when it was set to 1000 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit OS or 64-bit OS? I don't think you can mmap a memory portion over 3GB when using LInux 32-bit, and the value of UINT_MAX is 4GB-1.

Comment: uname -a returns:
`Linux os-class.engr.oregonstate.edu 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 20:57:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I think that's 64 bit. This is a school server for a school assignment so I doubt that the server wouldn't be able to handle it.

Comment: Never cast to `void *`. Also you should remove `(unsigned char*)` . As a general rule, casts can cause compiler warnings/errors to be suppressed so they should be avoided unless there is no alternative.

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after each printf; stdout is buffered

Comment: If `max` is `UINT_MAX`, and your platform has `int` and `long` the same size, then `max+1` will be `0`. (But this code should work correctly because zero-length `memset` is permitted so long as the pointer is valid

Comment: "For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes." (Linux shm_open(3) man page).  The name you give does not satisfy those criteria.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, not if `unsigned long` is wider than `unsigned int` on this system.  That appears to be the case for 64-bit glibc, judging by its limits.h, and that's probably relevant to the 64-bit Linux system in question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger my comment covered that...

Comment: fixed the name passed into `shm_open()`, still doesnt work. I tried adding 1 to `max` and it was saved correctly (no overflow). Currently investigating if `object_size` overflows in anyway...

Comment: @loukouk, do you really need 4GB of memory for your IPC purposes?  That seems more than a little excessive.

Comment: I also flushed the buffer after the `printf()` statements, still the same result. It looks like it faults at `memset()`. Removing (void *) and other casts also did not change anything.

Comment: UPDATE: I commented out `memset()` and tried accessing the map manually. It works for a while, but I get a bus error when the index becomes too big (but still less than `UINT_MAX`). It seems like the map I created isn't big enough, yet I check the `object_size` and it is equal to `UINT_MAX+1`. Any ideas??

Comment: This does not create a bus error: `printf("%c",address[1073741823]);` ______ But this causes a bus error
`printf("%c",address[1073741824]);`  IT FAILS AT EXACTLY `UINT_MAX/4` !!

Comment: Just out of interest, how *big* is the file while the program is running (just do `getchar()`  before the `memset()` to pause it)? SIGBUS is usually because the file isn't big enough. If it's not the fill 4G or whatever you've asked for, you might be hitting `ulimit` or something like that.

Comment: How big is which file? The memory map object? I looked it up and it said 0...     `-rw-rw----. 1 morriluk upg48923      0 Aug  4 17:05 .map_object
`

Comment: Wow I just ran it on a different machine and it worked :O

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you *one* thing you should do, that's flushing and syncing the output buffers. It may well be that you *are* actually printing `4` but it's being lost because of the crash.

In other words, wherever you have:

```
printf("something");
```

change it to:

```
printf("something"); fflush(stdout); fsync(fileno(stdout));
```

This will ensure that the buffers are flushed because, if they're not when you *crash,* you may well lose the information. The `fsync()` itself may not be necessary, I use it just to be safe.

Comment: I have flushed the output buffers, and the error still happens in the same location, at `memset()`. I tried commenting out `memset()` and accessing the map manually, and it gives me a bus error anytime i try to access any index that is greater than `UINT_MAX/4`. Any ideas what could be causing this error? Does it mean my map is not big enough? I tried using a larger `object_size` and got the exact same error at the exact same indexes